# Making dynamic url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to view profile of the user through their URL in search results. Here is the code:

```js
obj.forEach(function(element) {
  var url = "localhost:3000";
  url += "/doc/"
  url += element.username;
  console.log('url:' + url);
  console.log(element);
  $('.deneme').append("<a href= {url}>" + "<div class='username'>" + element.name + "</div>" + "</a>")
}, this);
```

The problem is I am not being redirected the URL.

Comment: If I read your code correctly, all you're doing is manipulating the DOM.  That won't get you a redirect.

Comment: What is the function currently doing and how is that behavior different than what you want it to do?

Comment: `href= {url}` won't work like you expect.

Comment: @coders: Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/f0pe52da/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var url` is a parameter so you can:

```
$('.deneme').append("<a href=" +url+">" + (every element you want to add)
```

Comment: Lol we submitted the same answer at the same time :)

Comment: @Samyok yeah :D